# How can I Make the User get a Notification When Another User Sends him a Chat Message

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

So I'm using the Firebase and React to make a chat.

And I need to notify the user when another user sends him a message in the chat.

Is there an easy way to do it.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

---

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
**Input.js** File with sending system.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Img from "../../static/chat/add-img.png";
import Attach from "../../static/chat/attach.png";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import { ChatContext } from "./ChatContext";
import {
  arrayUnion,
  doc,
  serverTimestamp,
  Timestamp,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, storage } from "../../firebase";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data } = useContext(ChatContext);

  const handleSend = async () => {
    if (img) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, uuid());

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, img);

      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          //TODO:Handle Error
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "chats", data.chatId), {
              messages: arrayUnion({
                id: uuid(),
                text,
                senderId: currentUser.uid,
                date: Timestamp.now(),
                img: downloadURL,
              }),
            });
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "chats", data.chatId), {
        messages: arrayUnion({
          id: uuid(),
          text,
          senderId: currentUser.uid,
          date: Timestamp.now(),
        }),
      });
    }

    await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), {
      [data.chatId + ".lastMessage"]: {
        text,
      },
      [data.chatId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
    });

    await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", data.user.uid), {
      [data.chatId + ".lastMessage"]: {
        text,
      },
      [data.chatId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
    });

    setText("");
    setImg(null);
  };
  return (
    <div className="input">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        value={text}
      />
      <div className="send">
        <img src={Attach} alt="" />
        <input
          type="file"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <label htmlFor="file">
          <img src={Img} alt="" />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

**Message.js**The file that shows the messages.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import { ChatContext } from "./ChatContext";


const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data } = useContext(ChatContext);
  const ref = useRef();


  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={`message ${message.senderId === currentUser.uid && "owner"}`}
    >
      <div className="messageInfo">
        <img
          src={
            message.senderId === currentUser.uid
              ? currentUser.photoURL
              : data.user.photoURL
          }
          alt=""
        />
        <span>just now</span>
      </div>
      <div className="messageContent">
        <p>{message.text}</p>
        {message.img && <img src={message.img} alt="" />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Message;
```

Can you help me Implement it.

Comment: Others can help you better if you can share what steps have you done and what specific blocker are you experiencing. For example, what specific feature are you stuck? This way others will be able to suggest any method that's applicable to your use case. You can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).